# How to enable the macOS badge icon for Slack direct messages?

Tags: slack

When I receive a direct message on Slack, I currently receive a sound notification. The the badge icon in the macOS dock doesn't show a number though.

[image]

How can I make Slack show the number of unread direct messages in the macOS Dock?

Answer (score 2):

In notification center, you must autorise Slack.

[image: Notification center]

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on [mickael's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1635421/167207).

To turn on the badge app icon for Slack in macOS' dock:

1. Open **System Preferences**
2. Click on **Notifications**
3. Scroll down to **Slack**
4. Make sure you have enabled **"Allow Notifications from Slack."**, the slider at the top should be blue.
   Then you can select which kind of notification you want. Enable **"Badge app icon"** to get numbers to reappear.

[image: in Notifications, you can turn badges, sounds, alerts and banners to show up for many of the apps you have in your Apple dock]

See also:

- Slack: [Guide to Slack notifications, section *App icon notifications*, tab "mac"](https://slack.com/help/articles/360025446073-Guide-to-Slack-notifications-Guide-to-Slack-notifications#mac-btn-2)
- Gearbrain: [How to turn Slack badges back on with macOS 10.15 Catalina](https://www.gearbrain.com/slack-badges-on-macos1015-catalina-2641088794.html)
- Zapier: [How to turn off the red dot in Slack](https://zapier.com/blog/turn-off-red-dot-slack/)

Comment: How is this answer different from the already [posted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1635421/167207) from 3 years ago? Granted yours is more detailed and shows English screenshots but still.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 For that 2 reasons. That's why I decided not to edit that link-only answer like you did.

Comment: Good point. Fair enough.